# how to set a python while loop stop after 3 times?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to Python, I want to condition my while loop stop after 3 times, please, help!

## Let's get up:-))

```
a =  "It's time. "
b = "Alarm rings!!! "
c = "Are you ready to get up ? "
print a +  b +  c
answer = raw_input("Enter Yes or No:  ")
if answer =='Yes':
  print "Climb Out of Bed"
while answer == 'No':
  print a + b + c
  answer = raw_input("Enter Yes or No: ")
```

Comment: Is it okay to use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter to keep track of the number of times you've looped.

```
a =  "It's time. "
b = "Alarm rings!!! "
c = "Are you ready to get up ? "
counter = 0
print a +  b +  c
answer = raw_input("Enter Yes or No:  ")
if answer =='Yes':
  print "Climb Out of Bed"
while answer == 'No' and counter < 3:
  print a + b + c
  answer = raw_input("Enter Yes or No: ")
  counter += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a for loop for fixed repetition instead:

```
for i in range(3):
    if answer == 'No':
        print a + b + c
        answer = raw_input("Enter Yes or No: ")
```